# Widget is not working

Tags: android, android-widget

I fired a activity from a widget class but activity open directly without use of widget but i want when i use widget then open activity but widget is not showing there please help me i am doing this from last two days but there is no progress

```
public class HomeScreen extends AppWidgetProvider {

@
Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_image, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.app.om" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.app.om.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".HomeScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Widget is not showing where? Please update your question to say what you did on the device and what happened.

Comment: @Dan Humble widget is not showing on device without widget,activity launched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What you want**

YOu want tapping on your widget shows activity

**What's happening**

Activity starting alone

**Solution**

Write an attribute in your widget provider like this

android:configure=""

and provide here the class package to be launched

and remove ACTION-MAIN and CATEGORY-LAUNCHER from the class MAinActivty from your manifest

**RESULTS**

NOw only widget remains and on click you come to your activity

hope it helps

Comment: in android:configure=""  i have to write "com.app.om.MainActivity" or  "com.app.om.HomeScreen"

Answer (score 0):

Installing a package that offers a widget doesn't automatically add the widget to the home screen. The user has to drag the widget from the **Widgets** list in the apps menu onto the right place in the home screen.

As @cafebabe1991 says, if you don't want the main activity to appear in the apps menu, remove its `intent-filter` from the manifest.